# Spring MVC error: The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

When I invoke this URL in the browser:

```
http://localhost:8080/app/foo.json
```

Spring responds with 406 Status code in this error message:

> The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers ().

However I have defined my content negotiating view resolver like this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="true" />
    <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />

    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
            <entry key="html" value="text/html"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And my controller is defined like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo")
public class ToowootController {

    @RequestMapping(method = GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public FooDTO index() {
        // return fooDTO
    }

}
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like the problem was that I had not added all the necessary dependencies, in this case `jackson-mapper-asl`. I thought only adding `jackson-core-asl` would be enough.

Answer (score 2):

@ResponseBody and ContentNegotiatingViewResolver are two alternatives for the same thing. You usually use one or the other, not both. Remove @ResponseBody if you want to use ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.

Answer (score 0):

When you use your website to **ContentNegotiatingViewResolver**  **ModelAndViews** return controllers or **view names** and the ContentNegotiatingViewResolver will, based on Various criteria, choose the right data representation strategy.

Therefore you can not only return an object DTO.

**Example Configuration**

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
  <property name="order" value="1" />
   <property name="mediaTypes">
    <map>
      <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
      <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
    </map>
  </property>
  <property name="defaultViews">
    <list>
       <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView"            />
    </list>
  </property>
 <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
</bean>


@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo")
public class ToowootController {

    @RequestMapping(method = GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView index() {

        return new ModelAndView("xxxx", "Foo", FooDTO);
    }
 }
```

The extension will tell Spring the content type to use when returning the data.

Answer (score 0):

The ContentNegotiationManager solve this problem. Im using spring 3.2. I have already answered, its working for me, especially for .json, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631992/spring-3-2-content-negotiation-class-cast-exception/14931063#14931063) .

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure if this will fix it, but I do see a problem with your code. The `@ResponseBody` annotation should come before the returned item, in this case, `FooDTO`. Also I hope you statically imported 'RequestMethod.GET'. Otherwise you should change 'GET' to 'RequestMethod.GET'. So the method should read:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody FooDTO index() {
        // return fooDTO
    }
```

Comment: No unfortunately this didn't change anything. Putting `@ResponseBody` before the return type is just a "style", otherwise Java does not support annotations on method return types at the moment. And yes, I've statically imported `RequestMethod.GET`.